# How do I get notified for DHCP renewal

Tags: macos, networking, notifications, dhcp

I would like to know an API for DHCP renewal notification in OSX.
Without polling, I would like to be notified when the IP address of my mac changes.
How can I do that?

Comment: FWIW, if you're staying connected to the same network, you're going to keep the same IP when you renew.

Comment: Excuse me for my bad explanation. I suppose a case when I moved between different networks, like home and an office.

Answer (score -1):

The question is meaningless. DHCP renewal doesn't change your IP address.